# Permissions system for a CMS

Tags: permissions, content-management-system, roles

does anyone know of a good tutorial for how to build a permissions and roles system for a CMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Permissions

Well, if you want a tutorial there are lots! However, if you want to implement something which will be easy to manage then I suggest you read up about Access control lists. ACL. 
If your site implements an ACL you will be able to manage permissions for lots of different roles very easily. Heck, just reading about them will be a great tutorial start point.

You can read about the Zend Framework ACL library here:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html